# webpack-dev-middleware serve/fallback to the public directory

Tags: express, webpack, webpack-2, webpack-dev-middleware

Project structure:

1. Webpack is building the app into the `public` folder
2. At the same time I have some static assets located there, like:
   `public/assets/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css`

What I want:

1. I want to run my `express` app with the `webpack-dev-middleware` for the dev purposes
2. I want that all the requests for the static assets (which are not processed by `webpack`) were served from the `public` folder

How I tried to do that:

**first attempt**

```
app.use(require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler, {
    stats: { colors: true }
}));

app.use(require('webpack-hot-middleware')(compiler));
app.use('/', feathers.static(app.get('public'))); // express.static
```

This works good, until you have `index.html` in the `public` folder. If you have it there - the static one would be served, **NOT** the one which is the actual version according to the `webpack-dev-middleware`.

**second attempt**

Then I thought - probably I must use `express.static` only for the production case, I removed it. Now I was not able to open `/assets/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css`

**third attempt (hack which works right now)**

Finally I made it work, but I'm not satisfied with the current solution. I manually put all the `assets` directory into the `webpack` realm by extending the webpack config with this:

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            { from: 'public/assets/', to: 'assets' },
            { from: 'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/', to: 'vendor/bootstrap/dist' }
        ]),
```

however this method assumes that one need to point every static file which he wants to be served by `webpack-dev-middleware`

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Regards,